# Create button with macro, that will copy from cell left of button

Tags: excel, vba

I have table like this, but bigger.

[image: Excel data]

My code:

```
Sub copy()
    Range("A2").Copy
End Sub
```

I want the button to adapt to the cell next to it as I copy it. From say, A2 to A3 to A4 etc.

Comment: Yes, this line is quite unclear "So, I want the button to adapt to the cell next to it as I copy it. Like it goes from say, A2 to A3 to A4". What are you trying to create, actual buttons to click? Or is it just a column with a header called Buttons? Also if that's column D, the cells to it's left would be column C, not A. Surely that's not all your code you got I may hope?

Comment: @JvdV Yea I want to create actual buttons to click that have attached macro to it. For now I make simple button in column B that copy text from column A cell 2 to clipboard.

Comment: My main problem is, how to copy buttons, like you do with cells fill tool and how to make macro adjust to cell left to it.

Comment: Something like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell` will return a reference to the top left cell that the button covers. `Application.Caller` will return the name of the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does essentially what you are trying to do:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rw As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    rw = .Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    .Cells(rw, 1).Copy
End With

End Sub
```

Assign this macro to all the buttons you have created in the cells on column B

---

If you need this on more buttons for example column D and F, and you want to copy respectively C and E, you could use a more generic piece of code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rw As Long, cl As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    rw = .Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    cl = .Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column
    .Cells(rw, cl - 1).Copy
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have created button in column D cell 2 in order to copy text from column C cell 2, but I get run-time error '9': out of range

Comment: @G.Dawid, as mentioned in my answer, you'll have to adapt the referenced sheet to the actual sheetname your buttons reside on. In other words, if `Sheet1` is not the correct sheetname, you'll recieve that error, and you'll just have to change it according to your actual sheet's name.

Comment: Is it posible to copy text that contains new lines with out quotes ""?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear.

If you are looking for a macro that would allow your button to copy the cell to its left,

you make your button as a range.

When you select, obtain the column and row of your selection.

```
Sub copy()

Dim TargetCell As Range

Set TargetCell = Selection

TargetCell(ActiveCell.column - 1, ActiveCell.row).Copy

End Sub
```

I hope this might be helpful to you in any way.

Comment: I guess it's based on my current active cell. When for example my click on column c cell 2, my button is in column D cell 2 it will copy text from cell 5 column F. I check that it's random. When I have button in column B it will copy cell 3 column D, etc..